# Boost::GIL: reading *.png image with alpha channel is missing antialiasing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

I'm using boost 1.74.

So, without exception catches and rest stuff my actual code looks like:

```
typedef std::vector<int32_t> FlatINT32TArr;

using PreviewImageT = bg::rgba8_image_t;
using PreviewViewT = bg::rgba8_view_t;
using PreviewPixelT = bg::rgba8_pixel_t;

void read_pixel_arr(FlatINT32TArr r_preview_flat_arr, const std::wstring& filepath)
{
  std::ifstream byte_stream(filepath, std::ios::binary);

  PreviewImageT image;

  bg::read_and_convert_image(
    byte_stream, image, bg::image_read_settings<bg::png_tag>());

  const int image_width = (int)image.width();
  const int image_height = (int)image.height();

  const int preview_pixel_count = image_width * image_height;

  PreviewViewT preview_view;
  PreviewPixelT* buff1 = new PreviewPixelT[preview_pixel_count];
  preview_view = bg::interleaved_view(
    image_width, image_height, buff1,
    image_width * sizeof(PreviewPixelT));

  bg::copy_and_convert_pixels(
    bg::flipped_up_down_view(const_view(image)), preview_view);

  r_preview_flat_arr = FlatINT32TArr(preview_pixel_count);
  memcpy(
    &r_preview_flat_arr[0],
    &preview_view[0],
    sizeof(PreviewPixelT) * preview_pixel_count
  );
}
```

It reads the * .png image file and converts it to int32_t array. (The array is then used to generate the OpenGL texture).

So, the original image file is:

[image: Original]

It was exported from Adobe Illustrator with alpha channel, deinterlaced.

Here I got few issues I can't solve:

- Subsampling.

[image] - here is result. As you can see, image is so much aliased as a stairs, why? How to solve it?

- Interlacing.

[image] - here is result. As you can see, is there one more line from image bottom on the top. Temporary it was solved by exporting deinterlaced image but it is not the best way. How can I solve it using gil?

One more test:
Original one (with alpha channel gradient):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I didn't think that's  what aliasing is. You mean it's pixelized?

Comment: @sehe , yes, pixelized. It looks like pixels on circle shape border is missing alpha channel. As you can see, result line width is a bit higher than original image has.

Comment: For some reason in areas where original image pixels was antialiased (shape borders), alpha channel value is clamped to 1.0f. Smth like:
`result_alpha = (original_alpha > 0.0f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong *after* the conversion shown.

When I save the preview data as PNG:

```
bg::write_view("output.png", preview_view, bg::png_tag{});
```

I get the expected output:

[image]

That's the preview buffer (`buff1`) precisely as you copy it  in the flat int32 vector.

> Note also
>
> - the return parameter was passed by value, meaning it would not actually be changed by `read_pixel_arr` (added `&` for pass-by-reference)
> - there was a memory leak, because `buff1` was never freed. Below, I fixed it with a `unique_ptr`.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50b9d1aa0ac8edd4)**

```
void read_pixel_arr(FlatINT32TArr& r_preview_flat_arr, std::string filepath) {
    std::ifstream byte_stream(filepath, std::ios::binary);

    bg::image_read_settings<bg::png_tag> settings;
    //settings._read_transparency_data = true;

    PreviewImageT image;
    bg::read_and_convert_image(byte_stream, image, settings);

    auto width   = image.width();
    auto height  = image.height();
    auto npixels = width * height;

    auto buff1 = std::make_unique<PreviewPixelT[]>(npixels);
    auto preview_view = bg::interleaved_view(
            width, height, buff1.get(),
            width * sizeof(PreviewPixelT));
    assert(buff1.get() == &preview_view[0]); // checking understanding

    bg::copy_and_convert_pixels(
            bg::flipped_up_down_view(const_view(image)), preview_view);

    r_preview_flat_arr = FlatINT32TArr(npixels);
    memcpy(r_preview_flat_arr.data(), 
           buff1.get(),
           sizeof(PreviewPixelT) * npixels);

    bg::write_view("output.png", preview_view, bg::png_tag{});
}

int main() {
    FlatINT32TArr v(1 << 20);
    read_pixel_arr(v, "sample.png");
}
```

### Much Simplified

Using `read_image_info` you can avoid allocating the buffer 3 times and copying it as many times:

1. for the image buffer (which is only used to copy from and detect width/height)
2. for the `buff1` (that was originally leaked as well)
3. for the flat array (`std::vector`)

Instead, let's detect the dimension from the file info, and read *directly* into the flat array:

```
auto flatvector_view(FlatINT32TArr& v, long width) {
    return bg::interleaved_view(
       width, v.size()/width,
       reinterpret_cast<PreviewPixelT*>(v.data()),
       width * sizeof(PreviewPixelT));
}

long read_pixel_arr(FlatINT32TArr& r_pixeldata, std::string filepath) {
    bg::image_read_settings<bg::png_tag> settings;
    auto info   = bg::read_image_info(filepath, settings);
    auto width  = info._info._width;
    auto height = info._info._height;
    r_pixeldata.resize(width * height);

    bg::read_and_convert_view(filepath,
        bg::flipped_up_down_view(flatvector_view(r_pixeldata, width)),
        settings);

    return width;
}

int main() {
    FlatINT32TArr v;
    auto width = read_pixel_arr(v, "sample.png");

    bg::write_view("output.png", flatvector_view(v, width), bg::png_tag{});
}
```

Note that the `reinterpret_cast` is guarded by the `static_assert`. It is logically equivalent to your `memcpy` type-punning.

---

Comment: yes. For sure, I just missing ampersand in question description sample code, its looking like mem leak;)
Unfortunetly, same way as before I have no direct access to draw code and all I can do - generate numpy array of pixels and set icon pixels from it. Here I am limited in data type usages (as you can see, I need int32_t 1D-array).
But your post is usefull as well, because it shows much more convient and right way to realize it, Thank you!

Comment: Sure. I was just helping you realize the problem exists outside the code shown. You can post other questions if you get stuck finding the cause further down. [I didn't assume the ampersand was missing in your real code as you would have surely seen different symptoms. To be completely sure, the memory leak was independent from that, but perhaps that's also less relevant]

Comment: Pretty terrible situation with documentation (as well as for `boost` at all;).
I got a crazy idea looking at `read_and_convert_view` usage in your code. Can it be used to generate previews (smaller versions of image) using smth like `bg::resize_view`? For example I have dataset of 500+ 8K images and I need generate previews for them. Previous implementation works good, it was < 30sec (running from SSD) but I think it can be better.

Comment: Yes. [padding] [padding] Seriously, if you want a review of that, consider posting on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Going deeper, I realized it using libpng itself.
After reading documentation of libpng, I found the issue can be solved using
`png_set_alpha_mode(png_ptr, PNG_ALPHA_PREMULTIPLIED, 1.0f);`
Strange that boost::gil do not provide such possibility.

Comment: @vanyOk To be honest, it sounds like that should do nothing (considering alpha is very much visibly enabled already), and the Boost GIL tests come with comprehensive tests for every color under the sun: https://github.com/boostorg/gil/blob/develop/test/extension/io/png/png_read_test.cpp/ It is simply more likely that there is a misunderstanding down the road. If you're more comfortable/find it easier to work with libpng docs, by all means, go that route.

Comment: I can see there used to be a bug with grayscale PNG with alphs at one time, which has added those to the tests https://github.com/boostorg/gil/pull/118

Comment: Yes, you right, for current task I rather would use libpng directly, its easy.
http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt
Also, according to documentation "This is the 'OPTIMIZED' mode.  For this mode a pixel is treated as opaque only if the alpha value is equal to the maximum value." So due to docs, libpng itself can write alpha channel values correct but still need `png_set_alpha_mode` call if you need to use them in your application.
I like the way of boost::gil, but not in this specific case (when I need only png's) files with very specific output format (int32_t array)

Comment: It's still weird. The information is clearly there, so it SHOULD also be in those int32 values. I suspect you can easily prove it by looking at a specific pixel and dumping the values. Mmm. Maybe I will myself

Comment: Maybe offtopic, but looks like `boost::gil` - its abandoned project. The most interesting that its the ONLY one image processing library which glue a few of native format libraries and allows io from streams (for example, OpenCV do not allow this and OpenImageIO allows but in a very limited way, not for all image types)

Comment: Yes, also you can temporary modify your local gil io reader with / without `png_set_alpha_mode ` to see a difference

Comment: And compare not resulted file, but an array of `int32_t`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225530/discussion-between-sehe-and-vanyok).